# XSLT define a variable and check if it exists after

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am attempting to transform an XML document. First, I am defining a global variable:

```
 <xsl:variable name="foo"><xsl:value-of select="bar"/></xsl:variable>
```

Now there is a chance that the XML I'm transforming has `<bar>some data</bar>` defined. There is also a chance that it is not defined.

Once I declare the global variable below, I'm trying to output the following if it is defined:

```
<foo>DEFINED</foo>
```

and if it's not defined:

```
<foo>NOT DEFINED</foo>
```

I am using `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: Variable `foo` is defined after the variable definition.  The only question is whether or not it contains a text node.

Comment: Is it better if I ask my question on how to check if a text node is defined or not?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the input contains `<bar/>` or `<bar></bar>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you could use `string()` to do the test.

Here's an example stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="foo" select="bar"/>
        <results>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string($foo)">
                    <foo>DEFINED</foo>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <foo>NOT DEFINED</foo>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>           
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that white-space is collapsed so `<bar> </bar>` will return false. Also, `string()` will work when testing an element directly instead of a variable.

Here's some input/output examples:

---

**Input**

```
<test>
    <bar/>
</test>
```

or

```
<test>
    <bar></bar>
</test>
```

or

```
<test>
    <bar>    </bar>
</test>
```

**Output**

```
<foo>NOT DEFINED</foo>
```

---

**Input**

```
<test>
    <bar>x</bar>
</test>
```

**Output**

```
<foo>DEFINED</foo>
```

---

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could declare the variable as an `xs:string` and just use the variable name in the test (`test="$foo"`).

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="foo" select="bar" as="xs:string"/>
        <results>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$foo">
                    <foo>DEFINED</foo>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <foo>NOT DEFINED</foo>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>           
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works but...

Add `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` to your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="fn:boolean(foo)">
    <foo>DEFINED</foo>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <foo>NOT DEFINED</foo>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Edit: @JimGarrison This will treat `<bar/>` or `<bar></bar>` as defined if it works.

Comment: You don't have to declare the `fn` prefix and it doesn't need to be added to `boolean()`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable foo will contain the xml node bar (not only the text which is content of bar) your xml contain bar.  Therefore the answer from "@indeterminately sequenced" is right you can test if foo contains a xml node (bar) with `test="boolean($foo)"`.  But I would  prefer 'test="name($foo)"`. Or test="name($foo) = 'bar'`
Which lead to:

```
<xsl:variable name ="foo" select="*/bar" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name($foo)">
                <foo>DEFINED</foo>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <foo>NOT DEFINED</foo>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </results>
</xsl:template>
```